# Powershell Export to Clicml from ForEach

Tags: powershell

I try to get result from this part of my powershell scrip into ***Clixml***.
I'm just beginner in powershell so i have kind of problem using arrays.

I'm unable to get result of this script into file.

```
$groupname = "Domain Admins"
$users = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname | ? {$_.objectclass -eq "user"}
foreach ($activeusers in $users) { Get-ADUser -Identity $activeusers | ? {$_.enabled -eq $true} | 
select-object SamAccountName  | Sort-Object -Descending | select-object SamAccountName }
```

Here is code used for export to Clixml

```
Export-Clixml -Path 'C:\TEMP\CurrentDomainAdmins3.xml'
```

Comment: replace you 2nd [duplicate and unneeded] `Select-Object` section of your pipeline with the `Export-CliXml` call.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning the result of `foreach () {}` to any variable, e.g. `$results = foreach () {}` and you cannot pipe the output of that style of loop to another cmdlet.

I don't think you need a loop for it at all; you could rewrite it like this:

```
$groupName = 'Domain Admins'
Get-AdGroupMember -Identity $groupName | 
    where-Object -Property ObjectClass -eq -Value User | 
    Get-AdUser |
    Where-Object -Property Enabled |
    Export-Clixml -Path 'C:\TEMP\CurrentDomainAdmins3.xml'
```

or for a more interactive style:

```
AdGroupMember 'Domain Admins' | ? ObjectClass -eq User | AdUser | ? Enabled
```